# How can you export an application/applet from Processing to Android?

Tags: java, android, applet, processing

I am using a java-based library called Processing and I need help exporting my mini-application to android. I have searched online and haven't found any resources or anyone do something like this.

**Thank You. Really appreciate all your answers!**

Comment: did you try using Android Studio? I am not sure, but you probably use use that to make an app using processing  [here](https://android.processing.org/tutorials/android_studio/index.html) is more info

Comment: Processing has an Android mode that should allow you to run your code on Android devices.